# How to increase the size limit of a SQLite database to 140TB?

Tags: database, performance, sqlite, resize

I'm writing to a SQLite DB in Java. Everything was going well for a few days, then suddenly everything crashed and I got the following stacktrace:

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_FULL]  Insertion failed because database is full (database or disk is full)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:921)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:886)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.executeBatch(DB.java:774)
        at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.executeBatch(CorePreparedStatement.java:79)
        at co.happy.GroupByWriteFile.run(GroupByWriteFile.java:51)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The disk is not full. Here's the output from `df -h`:

```
root@host:/output# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  8.7M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  1.9G  5.9G  24% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/xvdb1      2.0T  572G  1.3T  31% /input
/dev/xvdc1      2.9T  1.1T  1.8T  37% /output
```

Here's the contents of /output (which contains the db):

```
root@host:/output# ls -lrth
total 1.1T
drwx------ 2 root root  16K Aug 31 23:39 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.0T Sep  2 05:12 groupby.db
```

I've tried running the code on multiple servers, and I keep getting the same thing. There's probably about 1 billion rows in one table in the database, and another 200 million or so in the other. According to [SQLite's Limit page](https://sqlite.org/limits.html), the "The theoretical maximum number of rows in a table is 2^64," which I am nowhere near, and the maximum database size is, "the maximum size of a database file is 2147483646 pages. At the maximum page size of 65536 bytes, this translates into a maximum database size of approximately 1.4e+14 bytes (140 terabytes...)", which I'm also nowhere near.

Reading the above, my interpretation is that if I increase the page_size to 65536, then I'll be able to reach the 140TB maximum. However, I'm also reading that this can have a serious performance impact. Is this the correct way to achieve the 140TB? If not, what are the steps to increase the size limit to 140TB? How, if it all, does it impact performance?

**EDIT**

Adding the query:

```
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
    int i = 0;
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("REPLACE INTO groupByKeys VALUES (?, ?)");
        ps2 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO groupByVals VALUES (?, ?)");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            DedupeInstruction d = writeQueue.take();
            ps.setString(1, d.getOutFile());
            if (d.isHasCustom()) {
                ps.setInt(2, 1);
            } else {
                ps.setInt(2, 0);
            }
            ps2.setString(1, d.getOutFile());
            ps2.setString(2, d.getLine());
            ps.addBatch();
            ps2.addBatch();
            if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                ps.executeBatch();
                ps2.executeBatch();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the query you're running that generates this exception? You might be running into a problem where SQLite has to generate temp tables during query execution, which involves generating temporary files on disk. If your query is sufficiently large, it could very well be generating a file large enough to cause an out of space issue.

Comment: I checked that, and the last server I ran this on had a 2TB system drive with almost all of it free, and still the same issue, immediately. I've updated the question and added the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *only* way to increase the maximum database size is to increase the page size.

For huge databases, making the page size as large as possible is an improvement because you reduce the per-page overhead.

Even for normal database, the page size should be at least as large as the block size used by the file system, which is 4 KB nowadays. (Recent SQLite versions do this automatically, but your database has a page size of 512 bytes.)

You should set the page size before creating the database by executing [PRAGMA page_size](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_size). For an existing database, you'd have to run [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) afterwards, which is not something you'd want to do with a large amount of data.

---

Please note that REPLACE always deletes the old row if it exists; if most of these do not actually change the row, you can avoid much I/O by doing this with two statements.

Comment: Yeah, as it turns out VACUUM is not really an option on this large of a table. Looks like there's really no feasible way to resize a large database once you've started it. Thanks for the tip regarding REPLACE! It sped my code up code a bit removing that.