# Sqlite Issue SQLITE_FULL (database or disk is full)

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a small sqlite database, which currently is ~149 mb. I am using java to run a query on the database and sometimes I get the following error message:

```
[18:28:50 ERROR]: [MegaLogger] Couldn't execute MySQL statement: 
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_FULL]  Insertion failed because database is full (database or disk is full)
```

The Query is as follows:

```
SELECT *, data FROM death_log INNER JOIN items ON items.deathDate = death_log.deathDate WHERE killerUUID != 'N/A' AND diedUUID == '00000000-0000-0000-0009-01ffde9ec682' GROUP BY death_log.deathDate ORDER BY death_log.deathDate ASC LIMIT 30;
```

Running this same query on my local machine with DB Browser yields the following:

```
Execution finished without errors.
Result: 1 rows returned in 3838ms
```

I read in another thread a user was getting a similar error and it was suggested they remove the Group By / Order By clauses, I have tried removing them and still get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated, If I need to I can set up a mysql database if this is a sqlite issue but it seems silly for something that will not end up being a large database.

Tried removing the Order By and Group By clauses.

Comment: Sometimes applications encounter this error even though there is an abundance of primary disk space because the error occurs when writing into temporary disk files on a system where temporary files are stored on a separate partition with much less space that the primary disk.

Comment: Also see this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46012432/2310289 and think about doing a vacuum

Comment: I bet you a cup of Java that your database's filename is `/tmp/something_or_other.sqlite` and that you are running your program on a Linux / FreeBSD / some other UNIX-alike operating system. The `/tmp` file systems on such systems are sometimes size-constrained RAMdisks. If my guess is correct, try `/usr/tmp` instead.